# What this mean " Incorrectly Handled Query Assembly " in SQL injection?

Tags: sql, security, sql-injection

im reading book is about " **SQL-injection** " so i defaced a title
"**Incorrectly Handled Query Assembly**" what does this mean? and can you give me a example code ? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "[defaced a title](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deface)," but does your book not explain what it is?  Surely if there's a section about it in your book it at least explains what it is along with examples...

Comment: mean , there is a title in that book talked about " Incorrectly Handled Query Assembly" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might have understood SQL injection. *Incorrectly Handled Query Assembly* seems to mean incorrect construction of query string.

Think of a simple scenario where you have written a query to list the whole details of the (logged in) user. Let us

```
String part1="SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE TAG=' ";
part2=" ' AND ID=' ";
part3=" ';";
//Constructing query with user inputted tag and user ID
String query=part1+ user_entered_tag + part2 + user_id + part3;
//This is an unsafe construction of query.
```

If the user enters tag like this:

**`Abc' OR '2'='2' OR '1'='1`**

The query will become like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE TAG='Abc' OR '2'='2' OR '1'='1' AND ID='544678';
```

If the query is then executed, all the transactions will be fetched.

Thus unauthorized person will have access to data. This happens because a loophole is left in the construction of query. The developer should avoid such injection by adding type checking or using built-in features like *prepared statements* .